# Oracle VirtualBox problem

Tags: virtualbox, java, oracle, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu-Studio 20.04.2 LTS.

I installed Oracle VirtualBox 6.1 and, inside that VM, I installed MS-Windows XP-SP3 (directly from the original installation DVD).

That VM worked so fine until... I don't know what I did but... Now, each time I try to enter there, the whole system is frozen and I have to reset the computer.

Is there an "easy" way to fix the VM? ???

Comment: "*I don't know what I did but...*" kudos for honesty. What do your logs say?

Comment: The VM freezes, or the host OS freezes? Did you change the number of CPU cores the VM can use after installing WinXP?

Comment: Do you have a snapshot of this fresh WinXP VM?

Comment: @user535733 What logs are you talking about? All the system is frozen. I have to reset the computer. I guess any log is eliminated with that reset.

Comment: Your system's logs are located in /var/log. Logs would be close to useless if they were purged at every restart, so they are usually persistent.